# If $|f|+|g|$ is constant then each of $f, g$ is constant

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f,g: U \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be holomorphic on the open and connected subset $U$. If $|f| + |g|$ is constant on $U$ show that $f, g$ are constant on $U$.

What can we say about finite or countable number of holomorphic functions?

Comment: What have you tried? Where have you got stuck? Any kind of context for this problem?

Comment: your second sentence doesn't make any sense

Comment: It seems to fail already for $g=0$.

Comment: I do not get the @Urgje comment. I think this question is begging you to apply some theorem you know, such as the Liouville theorem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(complex_analysis).

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the linked question.